# How to get instances from dependency-injection container in unit tests?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

Let's say I have the following class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

class Foo(private val jsonMapper: ObjectMapper) {
    // ...
}
```

And the corresponding test:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class FooTest {

    private val jsonMapper = ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules()

    private lateinit var foo: Foo

    @Before
    fun makeFoo() {
        foo = Foo(jsonMapper)
    }
}
```

My issue with this is that I have to call `findAndRegisterModules` (to have `jsr310` support etc.) manually. I'd prefer to let Spring Boot decide how to construct my dependencies.

But the following fails because of `java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class FooTest(private val jsonMapper: ObjectMapper) {

    private val foo = Foo(jsonMapper)
}
```

So, what is the correct way to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test fails because JUnit4 tests need to have a no args constructor.

Also your test is not using Spring as you are using the *@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)* annotation. This runner allows to initialize your Mock objects and inject them into your test subject ([Javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html)).

If you want to use Spring to construct your test subjects and its dependencies you need to use a different set of anntotations (check this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) for more details):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest 
class FooTest {
   @Autowired
   lateinit var foo: Foo
}
```